# Arch Linux won't recognize USB keyboard or mouse

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, mouse

When I boot up my desktop computer, which runs dual Windows 10 and Arch, I can use the keyboard to select which OS to boot into, but if I choose Arch, my mouse and keyboard do not work when my computer boots to the desktop log in screen.

Answer (score 0):

What actually happened.

I have my keyboard and mouse plugged into a seven-port USB hub. Arch isn't detecting the hub. But when I plug the keyboard and mouse -- both are USB devices -- directly into my computer, Arch detects them.